# form not been submited after jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

On ducument load i protecting my form from 'not safe' submit:

```
$("#my_form").submit(function(event){event.preventDefault();});
```

And after button click form are checked and should be submited but nothing happens:

```
$('#submit_b').click(function(){
if ($('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') == 'E1')
{
//alert('ok' + $('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') );
$('#my_form')[0].submit();
}
else
{
if (($('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') !== 'E1') && ($('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') !== 'OTR')) {
//alert('Not E  ' + $('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') );
$('#my_form')[0].submit();
}
else
{
if ($('input[name=site]:checked', '#my_form').attr('id') == 'OTR'){
//alert('other');
$('#my_form')[0].submit();
}
}
}
});
```

Comment: @PatrickEvans since OP is calling `form.submit()` that wouldn't be a problem... calling the native `submit` method of an form element will not trigger the submit event

Comment: is there any element with name or id as submit in your page

Comment: But $('#my_form')[0].submit();
should submit

Comment: check your console to see if there are any errors.. also try to log `console.log($('#my_form')[0].submit)` in the click handler before calling submit

Comment: no not with same id name

Comment: can you share the relevant html as well.. also the result of the console logging I asked above

Comment: @ArunPJohny SCRIPT3: Member not found.

Comment: also which is the browser used

Comment: Please show us some HTML code.

Comment: IE 9 But in another pages i have same structure and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On you button option you need change name to `Submit` now is `submit`

Answer (score 0):

You added a handler to form submit event that always prevents it.

If `#submit_b` is an `<input>` with `type="submit"` located inside the form, you could do instead:

```
$('#my_form').submit(function(e){
    if (/*conditions are not met*/) {
         e.preventDefault();
         return; //this will just abort
    }

    //additional operations or do nothing, which will submit the form
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Undo the preventdefault just before submitting form.you can prevent default and undo it by using this approach.

```
function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

//prevent default
$("#my_form").bind("submit", preventDefault);

//undo prevent default
$("#my_form").unbind("submit", preventDefault);
```

write undo code line just before submit form inside your validation loops. this will work